# Obj-c - Alphabetizing array of dictionaries in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to sort the data in my tableview into alphabetized sections using the below code. That said, while the below doesn't crash, even though self.clients is populated with multiple dictionaries, self.finalfiltered (the result of filtering self.clients' @"last name" key) is returned empty? Any idea why this is happening? I've logged both self.clients, as well as [self.clientSections objectAtIndex:section] and both are populated as they should be. I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious.

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.clientSections = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"#", @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e", @"f", @"g", @"h", @"i", @"j", @"k", @"l", @"m", @"n", @"o", @"p", @"q", @"r", @"s", @"t", @"u", @"v", @"w", @"x", @"y", @"z", nil];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        
        return 27;
        
    }
    
    return 1;
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return self.clientSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString*)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   return index;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [self.clientSections objectAtIndex:section];
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    
    if (self.clients.count > 0) {
        
        self.finalfiltered = [self.clients filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K beginswith[cd] %@)", @"last name", [self.clientSections objectAtIndex:section]]];
        
    
        return [self.finalfiltered count];
        
    }
    
   
}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: Oh my gosh. Went back and stepped through super slowly... it seems to be crashing because some of the sections return empty. IE. if there's nothing filtered for the letter "E", and my tableview tries to populate a cell with data, crash. I logged the predicate on its own without trying to populate a cell, and results are populated for other letters as they should be. How can I fix this? Ie. "App, don't crash if there's no results for the letter E"... Ha ha! @koen